# PowerBI next month function is not rolling over a year, any advice?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, monthcalendar

I have a column called Snapshot Effective Period (next month) which is the Nextmonth([Snapshot Period]). This function stops when the snapshot period is 12/1/2021, what I expect to see is 1/1/2022 when the snapshot period is 12/1/2021. The value is not rolling over a year. Any advice?

Snapshot effective period next month c1 is a calculated column in date format.

```
Snapshot Effective Period (Next Month) c1 = NEXTMONTH('Forecast Detail'[Snapshot Period])
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

NEXTMONTH function should be used on Calendar

> Notes In order to use any time intelligence calculation, you need a
> well-formed date table. The Date table must satisfy the following
> requirements:
>
> All dates need to be present for the years required. The Date table
> must always start on January 1 and end on December 31, including all
> the days in this range. If the report only references fiscal years,
> then the date table must include all the dates from the first to the
> last day of a fiscal year. For example, if the fiscal year 2008 starts
> on July 1, 2007, then the Date table must include all the days from
> July 1, 2007 to June 30, 2008. There needs to be a column with a
> DateTime or Date data type containing unique values. This column is
> usually called Date. Even though the Date column is often used to
> define relationships with other tables, this is not required. Still,
> the Date column must contain unique values and should be referenced by
> the Mark as Date Table feature. In case the column also contains a
> time part, no time should be used – for example, the time should
> always be 12:00 am. The Date table must be marked as a date table in
> the model, in case the relationship between the Date table and any
> other table is not based on the Date.

https://dax.guide/nextmonth/

Instead of NEXTMONTH use  DATE

```
Snapshot Effective Period (Next Month) c1 = DATE( YEAR('Forecast Detail'[Snapshot Period]), MONTH('Forecast Detail'[Snapshot Period]) +1, DAY('Forecast Detail'[Snapshot Period]))
```